# drop table timing out using psycopg2 (on postgres)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I can't drop a table that has dependencies using psycopg2 in python because it times out. (updating to remove irrelevant info, thank you to @Adrian Klaver for the assistance so far).

I have two docker images, one running a postgres database, the other a python flask application making use of multiple psycopg2 calls to create tables, insert rows, select rows, and (unsuccessfully dropping a specific table).

Things I have tried:

- used psycopg2 to select data, insert data
- used psycopg2 to drop some tables successfully
- tried (unsuccessfully) to drop a specific table 'davey1' (through psycopg2 I get the same timeout issue)
- looked at locks on the table `SELECT * FROM pg_locks l JOIN pg_class t ON l.relation = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' WHERE t.relname = 'davey1';`
- looked at processes running `select * from pg_stat_activity;`

Specifically the code I call the function (i have hard coded the table name for my testing):

```
@site.route("/drop-table", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def drop_table():
    form = DeleteTableForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        tablename = form.tablename.data
        POSTGRES_USER= os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER')
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD= os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')
        POSTGRES_DB = os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB')
        POSTGRES_HOST = os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST')
        POSTGRES_PORT = os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT')
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect(database=POSTGRES_DB, user=POSTGRES_USER,password=POSTGRES_PASSWORD,host=POSTGRES_HOST,port=POSTGRES_PORT)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            sql_command = "DROP TABLE "+ str(tablename)
            cursor.execute(sql_command)        
            conn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
        except Exception as e:
            flash("Unable to Drop table " + tablename +" it does not exist","error")
            app.logger.info("Error %s", str(e))
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
    return render_template("drop-table.html", form=form)
```

Update 7/11 - I don't know why, but the problem is caused by either flask **@login_required** and/or accessing "**current_user**" (both functions are part of **flask_login**), in my code I import them as `from flask_login import login_required,current_user`. I have no idea why this is happening, and it really annoying.

If I comment out the above @login_required decorator it works fine, logs look like this:

```
2022-11-07 09:36:45.854 UTC [55] LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2022-11-07 09:36:45.854 UTC [55] LOG:  statement: DROP TABLE davey1
2022-11-07 09:36:45.858 UTC [55] LOG:  statement: COMMIT
2022-11-07 09:36:45.867 UTC [33] LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2022-11-07 09:36:45.867 UTC [33] LOG:  statement: SELECT users.user_id AS users_user_id, users.name AS users_name, users.email AS users_email, users.password AS users_password, users.created_on AS users_created_on, users.last_login AS users_last_login, users.email_sent AS users_email_sent, users.verified_account AS users_verified_account, users.email_confirmed_on AS users_email_confirmed_on, users.number_of_failed_runs AS users_number_of_failed_runs, users.number_of_logins AS users_number_of_logins, users.datarobot_api_token AS users_datarobot_api_token, users.document_schema AS users_document_schema, users.column_to_classify AS users_column_to_classify, users.column_name_for_title AS users_column_name_for_title 
        FROM users 
        WHERE users.user_id = 1
2022-11-07 09:36:45.875 UTC [33] LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
```

When I have the @login_required included in the code, the drop table times out and I receive this log:

```
2022-11-07 09:38:37.192 UTC [34] LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2022-11-07 09:38:37.192 UTC [34] LOG:  statement: SELECT users.user_id AS users_user_id, users.name AS users_name, users.email AS users_email, users.password AS users_password, users.created_on AS users_created_on, users.last_login AS users_last_login, users.email_sent AS users_email_sent, users.verified_account AS users_verified_account, users.email_confirmed_on AS users_email_confirmed_on, users.number_of_failed_runs AS users_number_of_failed_runs, users.number_of_logins AS users_number_of_logins, users.datarobot_api_token AS users_datarobot_api_token, users.document_schema AS users_document_schema, users.column_to_classify AS users_column_to_classify, users.column_name_for_title AS users_column_name_for_title 
        FROM users 
        WHERE users.user_id = 1
2022-11-07 09:38:37.209 UTC [38] LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2022-11-07 09:38:37.209 UTC [38] LOG:  statement: DROP TABLE davey1
```

I have even tried putting a "time.sleep(10)" in my code to wait for rogue database transactions to rollback (which from the logs seems like the login_required is causing perhaps?!.

I am lost on how to fix this, or even debug further.

Comment: What error shows up in the db server's log file?

Comment: Your last image cuts off the data to the right (one reason not to post text as images....).  What was in the "granted" column?

Comment: Thanks @jjanes, i have updated the complete result of the query (and trying to find the logs.)

Comment: Is `davey1` the child or the parent in the FK relationship?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, thanks for the question. The "davey1" table is a child of the parent "users" table (each "user" will have a single row in the "users" (parent) table, with a corresponding unique child table of their "name" and unique "id" (in this case "davey1", in the next case "greg2", and the next user "shirley3", etc)... These tables will contain many rows that are specific to that user. Hope that answers the question.

Comment: Then there is no point in adding the `CASCADE` as the parent table `users` is not dependent on the data in `davey1`. You would have to do this if you where dropping `users`. In `psql` do `\d davey1` to get the table definition and update your question with that information **as text, not as an image**.

Comment: Updated with the describe table info.. I was adding CASCADE because I thought would drop the dependencies (sequence, index, etc). Possibly incorrect reasoning? Also I may be doing something fundamentally incorrect at the create table statement.. Will investigate and post that create statement (in case it helps)

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` statement is not necessary the `\d` provided the information needed. Where is `drop_database_table()` being actually called?

Comment: Thanks for your persistence with this @AdrianKlaver I appreciate it, it's the last thing i need to solve before pushing this live! I have tested getting rid of the "drop_database_table()" function and calling the "drop table" directly within the flask route/end point "/drop-table" endpoint (with the same result)... I have also tried using sqlalchemy with same time out issue... What is confusing me is:
1) other dummy tables can be dropped with this code (other than 'davey1')
2) the 'davey1' table can be dropped using psql and dbeaver

Comment: To me it looks like it is not committing and/or closing the connection. What happens if you use `psycopg2` directly, outside the Flask application?

Comment: Using psycopg2 outside of Flask (from the same docker image), everything works fine... Just can't work out why Flask seemingly locks up the DB?!!! :-(

Comment: So are you logging in the current_user before you running `drop_table()`?

Comment: I was using @login_required (and ensuring that the user was logged in prior to the drop-table function) but not any more, because I encounter the "locking" issue...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with only including the **psycopg2-binary==2.9.5** module in my requirements file... I needed to also include  **psycopg2==2.9.5**

I don't completely understand why, but this was the solution to the problem (I found this when deploying my docker image to AWS-ECS and seeing that my uwsgi process was crashing due to psycopg2)

Thank you @AdrianKlaver for your assistance.